# Web API and AngularJS - ajax request response with 401 unauthorize even though authenticated

Tags: javascript, angularjs, authentication, asp.net-web-api2, form-authentication

Problem: I do request to web api and that authenticate and set formauthentication cookie. Post to that, from angular JS, on each `$http` request it just goes to `401` unauthorized access as each web api controller has `[Authorize]` attribute.

Can you please help here how do I resolve this login/authentication issue.

Below is all code:

web api has following sign in:

```
 public HttpResponseMessage SignIn(UserModel user)
        {
            try
            {
            if (this.ModelState.IsValid)
            {                
                if (user.UserName == "final" && user.Password == "final")
                {
                    var response = this.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, "success");
                    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.UserName, false);                    
                    return response;
                }
                return this.Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized,"noaccess");
            }
            return this.Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest,"badrequest");
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return this.Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, "internalerror");
            }
        }
```

angular JS  sign in service:

```
function login() {            
            vm.dataLoading = true;
            authenticationService.Login(vm.username, vm.password).then(function (d, status, xhr) {                
                if (d.data == "success") {
                    authenticationService.SetCredentials(vm.username, vm.password);
                    $location.path('/');
                } else {                                                                
                    //"Invalid credentials. Please try again.";
                }
                vm.dataLoading = false;
            }, function (d) {                
                if (d.data.message != "internalerror") {                    
                    // "Invalid credentials. Please try again.";
                } else {
                    // "An error has occurred while login. Please try again.";
                }
                vm.dataLoading = false;
            });
        }
```

authenticationService - SetCredentials method:

```
function SetCredentials(username, password) {
            var authdata = Base64.encode(username + ':' + password);

            $rootScope.globals = {
                currentUser: {
                    username: username
                   ,authdata: authdata
                }
            };

            // set default auth header for http requests
            $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + authdata;

            // store user details in globals cookie that keeps user logged in for 1 week (or until they logout)
            var cookieExp = new Date();
            cookieExp.setDate(cookieExp.getDate() + 7);
            $cookies.putObject('globals', $rootScope.globals, { expires: cookieExp });

        }
```

After login, AJAX Calls as follow:

```
 this.Retrieve = function (fileName) {
                    return $http({
                        method: "POST",
                        url: config.APIURL + 'space/Retrieve',
                        data: JSON.stringify({ Name: fileName }),
                        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
                    });
                };
```

Packet info post to login and giving 401 access:

```
Request URL:http://localhost/pr.WebAPI/api/space
Request Method:GET
Status Code:401 Unauthorized
Remote Address:[::1]:80


Response Headers
view source
Cache-Control:no-cache
Content-Length:68
Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8
Date:Fri, 13 Jan 2017 09:43:58 GMT
Expires:-1
Pragma:no-cache
Server:Microsoft-IIS/10.0
X-AspNet-Version:4.0.30319
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET

Request Headers
view source
Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch, br
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:.ASPXAUTH=9C338EBAA4F9B02D8D28D6B0BB34B03E4EEBF2BEB29C8BAE79496236FBD3132C3B4F4CCC6F072C5A69C033E6867341B1C1729399B5B4EEDBD79E4160EE857476A342DF166260EF4663033FC2B25C2A47435CCD09966C9EA1EE8BDBD8BAA50E19
Host:localhost
Referer:http://localhost/pr.Web/app/views/Index.html
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36
```

Comment: Hi ..what if you rtry to set  $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + authdata; instead of Basic?

Comment: ok, let me do and share here.

Comment: perfect if it is correct i'll post as an answer

Comment: its not work. I applied 'Bearer'. though giving `401` exception.

Comment: but the strange thing is that you're not using standard webapi token auth .. with don't you take token from back end and use it instead of create your own doing    var authdata = Base64.encode(username + ':' + password);

Comment: @dsoni try to remove `$http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + authdata;` row.

Comment: I have tried by skipping `http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization']` line but gives `401`. It may be because, `[Authorize]` of web api expecting authenticated cookie.

Comment: @dsoni when you call `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.UserName, false);` it creates cookie for request and push it back with response. After it every time you make request browser automatically send cookies with data, created at the `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.UserName, false);`. So you diffinitelly should not modify headers. Headers modification is required for another types of authorization.

Comment: I have tried by removing and also,seen ASPXAuth cookie in response and same is posted after login requests but still getting 401 error. I have updated question to include request/response packet.

Comment: @federico-scamuzzi can you give example or any code regarding, I need for angular what need to pass and how to implement that on web api if other then form authenticaiton.

Comment: hi just create a webapi 2 asp.net poject ..when you choose the template it give you the individual authentocation as default and you have it!!! the you can call the /Token endpoint and have the token back

Comment: how it validate the username/password and where it needs to configure for register and login  requests.?                                           Another thing, Is possible to have formauthentcaiton how we can have MVC or asp.net application.?